# Why does this case block not execute?

Tags: c++

I've just started trying C++ a couple weeks ago. I got a pretty decent grip on Java before trying C++. A lot of people told me they are really similar in a sense of syntax.

There is a switch statement at the bottom initiating the fight scene. Whenever I choose the option to fight, it just closes the program.

Here is my code:

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include <iostream>
#include <cstdlib>     // For rand()
#include <string>
#include <sstream>
#include <algorithm>   // transform()
#include <cctype>      // toupper(), tolower()
#include <functional>  // ptr_fun()
#include <time.h>
// PUT S*** BELOW THIS POINT
//____________________________________________________________________________

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    /*    Expirimental text based adventure game.
     *    Mainly being used for practice methods.
     *    Developed by Zack Cook.

     Generic title. Bad story. Bad interactions. 

     Lots and lots of bad, bad code. Be warned.
     */   

    string charName;

    string charChoice;

    int charDecision;

    int playerHealth = 100;
    int randomNumber;
    int orcHealth = 100;

    srand (time(NULL));

    cout << "_____________________________________________" << endl;
    cout << "|   #####   #########     ###     ###   ### |" << endl;
    cout << "| ###   ###    ###      ### ###    ### ###  |" << endl;
    cout << "|   ###        ###     ###   ###    #####   |" << endl;
    cout << "|     ###      ###     #########     ###    |" << endl;
    cout << "| ###   ###    ###    ###     ###    ###    |" << endl;
    cout << "|   #####      ###    ###     ###    ###    |" << endl;
    cout << "_____________________________________________" << endl;
    cout << "" << endl;
    cout << "" << endl;
    cout << "Welcome player. What is your name?" << endl;
    getline(cin, charName);
    yesOrNo:
    cout << "Hello " << charName << ". Are you ready to begin?" << endl;

    getline(cin, charChoice);

    transform( charChoice.begin(), charChoice.end(), charChoice.begin(), toupper );
    cout << charChoice << endl;
    if(charChoice == "YES"){
        cout << "Good. Let's begin." << endl;
    }
    else if(charChoice == "NO"){
        system ("exit");
    }
    else
    {
        cout << "That is not a good answer." << endl;
        goto yesOrNo;
    }

    cout << "Our story begins with a wanderer named " << charName << " passing through the small town of Hark's Pass." << endl;
    cout << "A little cozy village with no more than 30 or so home stayers.\nThe village men work hard on the farms during the day." << endl;
    cout << "The women cater to the children, and other house hold chores.\nIn the evening, most of the village turns to The Rusty Trough for a bit of drink." << endl;
    cout << "As the sun starts to set, our wanderer, " << charName << ", starts foot towards The Rusty Trough." << endl;
    cout << "As " << charName << " enters the tavern, a heavily drunken Orc man stumbles towards the entrance." << endl;
    cout << "\"I've never seen you 'round here!\" The orc says to our wanderer. \"I think it's time to teach these adventure types what we really think about 'em\"" << endl;

    cout << "" << endl;
    cout << "What will you do?" << endl;
    cout << "1| Get ready to fight!" << endl;
    cout << "2| Call for help!" << endl;
    cout << "3| Try to run!" << endl;
    cout << "4| Do nothing at all!" << endl;
    cout << "5| Try to reason!" << endl;

    cin >> charDecision;

    switch(charDecision)
    {
    case '1': 
        do{
            cout << "FIGHT" << endl;
            randomNumber = rand() % 100 + 1;
            if(randomNumber >= 50){
                orcHealth = orcHealth - (randomNumber - (randomNumber / 5));
            cout << "You hit the orc! He now has " << orcHealth << " life left!" << endl;
            }
            else
            {
                playerHealth = playerHealth - (randomNumber - (randomNumber / 5));
                cout << "The orc hit you! You now have " << playerHealth << " life left!" << endl;
            }
        }while(playerHealth || orcHealth != 0);
        break;

    default:
        break;
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: `goto`? Uh oh. http://www.u.arizona.edu/~rubinson/copyright_violations/Go_To_Considered_Harmful.html

Comment: `while(playerHealth || orcHealth != 0)`? Almost certainly not what you wanted.

Comment: @Chris, While this is a terrible use, and I haven't seen a real use for `goto` in C++, that article is outdated to be honest. `goto` does have uses, but this isn't one of them.

Comment: @JerryCoffin: Funnily enough, it probably does the right thing (but is worth pointing out nonetheless).

Comment: @JerryCoffin I probably messed that up, huh?

Comment: You don't want `system ("exit")`. Use `exit()` (http://linux.die.net/man/3/exit).

Comment: @Hyrax77 Please create a new question when you have a new problem. Also think about your `while` condition as this will probably be why it loops endlessly.

Comment: @Chris Sorry about that. I'm pretty new here. I made a new post.

Comment: @Hyrax77 It is also customary to accept the answer that has helped you out. You can do that by clicking the light grey checkmark next to the answer that you want to accept.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Your switch statement compares an `int charDecision` with `'1'` which is a `char`.

You read from standard input into an `int` which means `charDecision` will contain 1. You then compare this 1 against `'1'` which translates to 49 when casted to `int`. Thus your input will never match (unless you input 49).

Fix: Compare against `1` or make `charDecision` a `char`.

Comment: Also, declaring variables not old-C-style at the beginning but just before they are actually used, may help in avoiding such errors.

Answer (score 5):

The variable `charDecision` is declared as an `int`.

The C++ standard I/O streams classes (including `cin` and `cout`, among other things) are relatively intelligent, and "do the Right Thing" based on the type of the variable you give it.

When the expression `cin >> charDecision` is executed, `cin` reads everything that looks like a number *and converts it into the native representation of the number.* So, when you type `1` on that menu, what gets stored is the literal number 1. Your switch is testing the literal *character* `'1'`, which has the integer value of 49, so it will not match, since 49 != 1.

You will want to either change the type of `charDecision` to `char` **or** test the number `1` instead of the character `'1'`.

Comment: Might be a good opportunity to read about [Enums](http://www.enel.ucalgary.ca/People/Norman/enel315_winter1997/enum_types/) as you may find them useful for your game.

Answer (score 0):

`while (playerHealth != 0 || orcHealth != 0)`
I think that is the problem.

Comment: I think instead of ||, && will work though. Because either one has to be zero for it to terminate. If say orcHealth is zero and playerHealth is not zero then it should terminate but it wouldnt.

Answer (score -2):

Your main problem is using goto, get rid of it!

```
yesOrNo:
cout << "Hello " << charName << ". Are you ready to begin?" << endl;

getline(cin, charChoice);

transform( charChoice.begin(), charChoice.end(), charChoice.begin(), toupper );
cout << charChoice << endl;
if(charChoice == "YES"){
    cout << "Good. Let's begin." << endl;
}
else if(charChoice == "NO"){
    system ("exit");
}
else
{
    cout << "That is not a good answer." << endl;
    goto yesOrNo;
}
```

can be replaced by

```
do
{
    cout << "Hello " << charName << ". Are you ready to begin?" << endl;

    getline(cin, charChoice);

    transform( charChoice.begin(), charChoice.end(), charChoice.begin(), toupper );
    cout << charChoice << endl;
    if(charChoice == "YES"){
        cout << "Good. Let's begin." << endl;
        startGame();//it is the function where you should place your game logic, the "switch" block in your case
        //if you want to get back to main menu after the end of the game you can delete next line:
        break;//leave this loop
    }
    else if(charChoice == "NO"){
        break;//leave this loop
    }
    else
    {
        cout << "That is not a good answer." << endl;
    }
} while (true);
```

Also doing this way you can go back to main menu after the end of the game.
I'd also recommend you to split your game logic to different functions, the code will be much easier to write and maintain. Also I'd recommend to rewrite your game in object-oriented way after you finish, it can be a good practice for you. And forget about `goto`, it can turn any code to a piece of crap.

Comment: Well the answer did not address the issue but rather lashed out against `goto` (-1) which in this case was pretty innocent. If anyone read beyond the abbreviated title of the document Chris posted above they would realise it is about non-local `goto`s; and this here is very much a local `goto` used as a loop construct, pretty innocent. Continuing, the answer goes on to show a better program structure with a proper loop and functions providing a major increase to maintainability and readability (+1). Net nothing from me.

Comment: @r_ahlskog, yes, it's not an answer to the question, but we can say for sure that this question's author is learning, so I think it's a good idea to give him a little lesson. I'm just afraid that downvotes will make him think that my proposal is not a good way to go and he'll stay with goto until he will try to write something big and then just forfeit his efforts to learn programming because it's soooo hard to modify the code containing goto. Maybe answer is not a good place for it, but I can't explain it in a comment's format

Comment: I can sort of understand, but I still have an issue with pointing it out as the cause when it was unrelated, this is how cargo cult programming develops. Regurgitating the "goto is bad" mantra is not something I consider a valuable programming skill. I think you did good in showing a better program structure using a proper loop instead of `goto` and if the author understands the improvements it will bring to his code then he is well off. But `goto` is still a tool in the toolbox and if we can't trust software developers to use their brains we are truly lost.

Comment: @r_ahlskog, I think `goto` have really not much of use, but can cause a geat troubles if not used right, so it's common to teach new programmers that `goto` is bad. When he will have enough experience, he can change the opinion about `goto`, but before it programmer should learn to write a good code, which is free of `goto` in 99+% cases. Take it as "goto is bad" mantra works only on those who don't yet ready to use `goto` ;)

Comment: well wars have been started over less so I will settle on that we see things differently. My mind works in such a way that I reject all arbitrary rules that people state, I consider such rules limiting to my ability to learn and explore a subject.